# Unable to create 'Azure VM' with Custom Image Using 'Ansible'

Tags: ansible, azure-virtual-machine, ansible-template

I am trying to automate the process of updating an image in the scale set. So, I wrote an Ansible playbook to create a VM from a custom image and then, later, make some changes in that VM, capture an image of the said VM and change the image reference in the scale set. But I am getting the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error creating or updating virtual machine vmss_update_vm - (InvalidParameter) Parameter 'osProfile' is not allowed.\nCode: InvalidParameter\nMessage: Parameter 'osProfile' is not allowed.\nTarget: osProfile"}
```

The play looks like this:

```yaml
- name:
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    resource_group: {{resource_group }}
    shared_gallery_name: linux_build
    shared_image_name: linux_build
    shared_image_version: 0.0.1
    admin_username: ubuntuadmin
    admin_password: Ubuntuadmin@123
    vm_name: vmss_update_vm
    vmss_name: testbuild2
  tasks:
  - name:  Create VM using shared image
    azure_rm_virtualmachine:
      resource_group: "{{ resource_group }}"
      name: "{{ vm_name }}"
      vm_size: Standard_D2s_v3
      managed_disk_type: Standard_LRS
      admin_username: testadmin
      admin_password: Pass123@
      image: 
        id: "/subscriptions/{{subscription_id}}/resourceGroups/{{resource_group}}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/linux_build/images/linux-build/versions/0.0.1"
        # name: linux-build
```

On further research, I found out that I was providing the `admin_user` and `admin_password` along with a custom image which is not allowed.

[image: Error message description from microsoft]

So, I removed the `admin_user` and `admin_password` and ran the playbook again:

```yaml
- name:
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    resource_group: {{resource_group }}
    shared_gallery_name: linux_build
    shared_image_name: linux_build
    shared_image_version: 0.0.1
    vm_name: vmss_update_vm
    vmss_name: testbuild2
  tasks:
  - name:  Create VM using shared image
    azure_rm_virtualmachine:
      resource_group: "{{ resource_group }}"
      name: "{{ vm_name }}"
      vm_size: Standard_D2s_v3
      managed_disk_type: Standard_LRS
      admin_username: testadmin
      admin_password: Pass123@
      image: 
        id: "/subscriptions/{{subscription_id}}/resourceGroups/{{resource_group}}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/linux_build/images/linux-build/versions/0.0.1"
        # name: linux-build
```

But after that I am getting the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Parameter error: admin_username required when creating a virtual machine."}
```

Do you have any idea how can I deal with this?